# Showing Greeting Message in Javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I display a greeting message according to the time of the day in javascript?

```
var greetdate=new Date()
var hours=greetdate.getHours()

document.write('<h2>Hello! Good Morning! Have a nice day.</h2>')

document.write('<h2>Good Noon Visitor! </h2>')

//MESSAGE FOR AFTERNOON
document.write('<h2>Good Afternoon! </h2>')

//MESSAGE FOR EVENING (6pm-8pm)
document.write('<h2>Good Evening! </h2>')

//MESSAGE FOR NIGHT (9pm-11pm)
document.write('<h2>Good Night! </h2>')

//MESSAGE FOR LATE NIGHT (12pm-4am)
document.write('<h2>Wow! You`re still awake. Working Late?</h2>')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var greetdate=new Date()
var hours=greetdate.getHours()
 
if (hours>=5&&hours<=11) 
//MESSAGE FOR MORNING
document.write('<h2>Hello! Good Morning! Have a nice day.</h2>')
else if (hours==12) 
//MESSAGE FOR NOON
document.write('<h2>Good Noon Visitor! </h2>')
else if (hours>=13&&hours<=17) 
//MESSAGE FOR AFTERNOON
document.write('<h2>Good Afternoon! </h2>')
else if (hours>=18&&hours<=20) 
//MESSAGE FOR EVENING (6pm-8pm)
document.write('<h2>Good Evening! </h2>')
else if (hours>=21&&hours<=11) 
//MESSAGE FOR NIGHT (9pm-11pm)
document.write('<h2>Good Night! </h2>')
else 
//MESSAGE FOR LATE NIGHT (12pm-4am)
document.write('<h2>Wow! You`re still awake. Working Late?</h2>')
```

Answer (score 3):

Good usecase for a switch:

```
var h=(new Date()).getHours();
switch(true){
case h<13 :
  document.write('<h2>Hello! Good Morning! Have a nice day.</h2>');
break;
case h<=14 :
    document.write('<h2>Good Noon Visitor! </h2>')
break;
case h<18 :
    document.write('<h2>Good Afternoon! </h2>')
break;
case h<21 :
    document.write('<h2>Good Evening! </h2>')
break;
case h<24 :
    document.write('<h2>Good Night! </h2>');
break;
}
```

All outputs: http://jsbin.com/fesulamaga/edit?output

Answer (score 2):

```js
var now = new Date();
var hours = now.getHours();

var greetings = [
   {"tod": "latenight",
    "greet": "Wow! You`re still awake. Working Late?",
    "test": hours >= 24 || hours <= 4
  },
  {"tod":"night",
    "greet": "Good Night!",
    "test": hours >= 21 || hours <= 11
  },
  {"tod":"evening",
    "greet": "Good Evening!",
    "test": hours >= 18 && hours <= 20
  },
  {"tod":"afternoon",
    "greet": "Good Afternoon!",
    "test": hours >= 13 && hours <= 17
  },
  {"tod":"noon",
    "greet": "Good Noon Visitor!",
    "test": hours == 12
  },
  {"tod":"morning",
    "greet": "Hello! Good Morning! Have a nice day.",
    "test": hours >= 5 && hours <= 11
  }
];

var message = document.getElementById("message");
message.innerHTML = greetings.find(el=>el.test).greet;
message.className = greetings.find(el=>el.test).tod;
```

```css
h2.latenight {
  color: purple;
  background: #ccf;
}

h2.night {
  color: silver;
  background: #000;
}

h2.evening {
  color: navy;
  background: #eee;
}

h2.afternoon {
  color: red;
  background: #ffdede;
}

h2.noon {
  color: cyan;
  background: goldenrod;
}

h2.morning {
  color: blue;
  background: #ffe;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2 id="message" class="bla"></h2>
</div>
```

The code avoids using **document.write** which is generally regarded as a bad practice (see discussion [here](https://www.quora.com/Front-End-Web-Development-Why-is-using-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice)).  The script sets the content of a pair of H2 tags and their style according to the time of day.  Now that the code is self-documenting it is uncluttered by any comments.  Note, that the objects are in descending order according to value of the time of day ("tod") property to assure accurate testing.

The array applies its [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find?v=control) method to each of its elements until a true result occurs. The callback for find() consists of an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which returns the result of an object's test property.  When true, find() in turn returns that element, thereby facilitating setting the content.  This same technique also aids in styling the H2 tag.

Comment: if greetings would be an array, you could do mess.innerHTML=greetings.find(el=>el.test).greet; wich is a bit more DRY ;)

Comment: Thank you!  Excellent suggestion -- most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
function writeWelcomeMessage() {
    var d = new Date();
    var h = d.getHours();

    if(h < 12) {
        document.write('<h2>Hello! Good Morning! Have a nice day.</h2>')
    } else if(h < 18) {
        document.write('<h2>Hello! Good Day.</h2>')
    }
    // etc
}
```